# Can I uninstall .NET Framework duplicates?

Tags: .net, .net-framework-version

I am using Revo Uninstaller to manage the installations of the software on my PC. I want to remove the old and unneeded programs and found that there are multiple duplicates of .NET Framework installations for different languages.

For example there are:
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 SDK and 
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 SDK (Polski)

Is this how it should be or can I remove one of them as trash?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, unless something is really messed up, they're not "duplicates". You would generally only have a single version of each version of .Net, and as you noted possibly in multiple languages.

.Net versions are easy enough to uninstall from the "Install Programs/Features" control panel, however removing it will break anything that depends on that version of .Net.

There isn't any way I'm aware of to know what version of .Net every app on your machine requires and I don't know if your cleanup tool knows either, however it *should* be OK to remove any .Net versions that are for languages you don't use.

For example, as long as you have one version of 4.6.1, I don't think you'll break anything by uninstalling the extra copies for other languages.

On the other hand, if you do delete one and find out that you actually needed it, you can download it again from Microsoft.